# Where is /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public located?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel 5.2 and I got to the point where I am configuring homestead.yaml file. I understand that `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public` is where my project files should be located:

```
sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

I am on Windows 7 and I can't find where this `/home` folder is. Does anyone know where it is? Or is my laravel project located in another folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This folder is inside virtual machine. You need to map real folder on your PC (like `C:\Laravel\public`) to VM folder `/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public`.

You can use your VM with SSH client, like WinSCP and you'll see all folders there:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
login: vagrant
password: vagrant
```

Answer (score 1):

That configuration option is where you provide virtual hosts for various applications that you'll be using homestead for.

By default, when you configure homestead you specify a directory that you want mounted onto the virtual machine, for me it's `D:\Users\me\Projects\PHP`. Homestead mounts this folder to `/home/vagrant/Code`.

That path is for the virtual machine and only the last part after `/Code` has any connection with your actual Windows machine.

Answer (score -1):

It's by default located realtive to your home directory on windows, i.e.

```
C:\Users\[user]\Code
```

Note: you might want to create the **Code** folder first inside `C:\Users\[user]`